# dircolors "missing second token"

Tags: ls, colors, csh

I'd like to customize the colors of `ls` and as far as I understand the way to go is with `dircolors`.

I did:

```
dircolors > ~/.dircolors
```

Immediately after this I launch a terminal and get this error:

```
dircolors: /home/frank/.dircolors:1: invalid line;  missing second token
```

I have not changed anything in `~/.dircolors`. Running Ubuntu 11.10 x64.
The file looks like this.

```
    LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:';
export LS_COLORS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're using `csh`.

Try:

```
dircolors -c > ~/.dircolors
```

(Note: some setups use `.dir_colors` instead.)

Answer (score 11):

You can try

```
dircolors -p >.dircolors
```

It also can solve the problem

Comment: This is likely the only correct answer in this thread.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem under Ubuntu 12.04.
The solution was to edit the ~/.dircolors file to remove the second line ('export LS_COLORS')
and make the first line do the export:

export LS_COLORS='...

No, I have no idea why.

Comment: This is the answer, though don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

Preliminary assumption/expectation: the OP is somewhere running the command

```
dircolors /home/frank/.dircolors
```

probably in a bash config file as

```
eval "$(dircolors ~/.dircolors)"
```

From the man page for dircolors:

> SYNOPSIS
>          dircolors [OPTION]... [FILE]

and

> If  FILE  is  specified, read it to determine which colors to use for
>   which file types and extensions.  Otherwise, a precompiled database is
>   used.  For details on the format of these files, run 'dircolors 
>   --print-database'.

In other words, if you give dircolors a file argument, it expects a file format as given by 'dircolors -p'. Any other format will not work as intended *as you are then getting the output of dircolors as intended for updating environment variables in shells.* Deleting that second, "export", line may stop the error *but the result will not be what you expect if you ever try to edit your dircolors database file.*

The accepted answer by Mat likely was also the first answer that stopped the error message. **But will not be doing what you hope!**

Answer (score 2):

what I found the solution was:-
first of all check whether you have ~/.dircolors file or not?
if not then put this in your terminal:-

```
dircolors -p > ~/.dircolors
```

then open your zshrc file from any text editor you want for eg using sublilme:-

```
subl ~/.zshrc
```

and add these lines into that file:-

```
eval "$(dircolors ~/.dircolors)"
alias dir='dir --color'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

now you have got your solution done.
if you want to change the colors open .dircolors through your editor and change the value of the color and other stuffs.
go to this link for the colors : - http://linux-sxs.org/housekeeping/lscolors.html

Solution of other did not work for me. Perhaps because I am using zsh shell.

Answer (score 0):

But something is wrong here

```
user@PC:~$ dircolors -b > xxx
user@PC:~$ dircolors xxx
dircolors: xxx:1: invalid line;  missing second token
user@PC:~$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

only this works  no file based input

```
eval "$(dircolors -b)"
```

I believe the standard .bashrc might not be aligned
it says

```
test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
```

and it works with

```
test -r ~/.dircolors && . ~/.dircolors || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
```